# Being able to vote and arrange the votes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the list works! now for my next trick. I want users to be able to vote on those listed movies as many times as they want, and when they vote, I want those voted movies to be arranged in a list below "you're best films". Here is what I've got so far:

in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="movies.css">
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<title> 
Hello World 
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Favorite Movies</h1>
        <div id = "first">
            <input type="text" id="movie" placeholder="Movie">
            <button id="enter">Enter</button>
        </div>
    <div id="list"><u>Chosen Films:</u></div>
    <!-- <div>Chosen Films: <span id="list"></span></div> -->
    <!-- <div id="films"></div> -->
    <div id="best">You're Best Films:</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="movies.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in my js:

```
/ The function that creates the first list
$("#enter").click(
  function() {
    var movie = $("#movie").val();
    var list = (movie);
    $('#list').append('<p>' + '<button id="vote"></button>' + list + '</p>');
  });

// The function that is supposed to place the chosen movies in a list below "Your best films"
$("#vote").click(
    function() {
    var voted = $("#best").val();
    var best = (voted);
    $('#best').append('<p>' + list + '</p>');
    });
```

So the first function works, just need the second one.

Comment: what is your question? stackoverflow is not a code writing service...

Comment: Is this entirely client-side, or is there a server somewhere, presumably running a database, that manages every vote?

Comment: Its entirely client side. I already have the code. I just need to get it to work.

Comment: So if a user votes, and someone else comes along, how would the other users see the votes?

Comment: They should see the votes under "Your best films", which is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot cal `list` from your second function. It's out of Scope. So you need to store it or pass it. I suggest storing it in the Value of the button.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/810353L9/

**JQUERY**

```
// The function that creates the first list
$("#enter").click(function () {
    var movie = $("#movie").val();
    var $btn = $('<button />', {
        id: "vote",
        type: "button",
        text: "^",
        value: movie,
        click: function(){
            var vote = this.value;
            $("#best").append('<p>'+vote+'</p>');
        }
    });
    var $p = $('<p />');
    //$('#list').append('<p>' + '<button id="vote" value="'+list+'">Vote</button> '+list+'</p>');
    $p.append($btn, " ", movie);
    $p.appendTo("#list");
});

// The function that is supposed to place the chosen movies in a list below "Your best films"
/*$("#vote").live('click', function () {
    var voted = $(this).attr("value");
    console.log(voted);
    $('#best').append('<p>' + voted + '</p>');
});*/
```

This creates the vote button, and the vote button appends the next list.

Comment: Excellent. Thank You!